# Change a row into two different rows when resizing the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a row with two input columns:

```
    <div class="row first-row">
      <div class="column col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usr"
            >Sequence Number:</label
          >
          <input type="text" class="form-control sequence-number" id="usr" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column status col-6">
        <BaseDropdown
          label="Status:"
          :options="statusTypes"
          v-model="building"
          placeholder="Please select a status"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

I want to make this row into two rows when resizing the screen to mobile, not when rendered on mobile. It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this would be to use Flex. You could achieve this by reorganizing your html to include both fields in the column div like so:

```
<div class="row first-row">
    <div class="column col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usr">Sequence Number:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control sequence-number" id="usr" />
        </div>
        <div class="column status col-6">
            <BaseDropdown label="Status:" :options="statusTypes" v-model="building"
                placeholder="Please select a status" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then apply flex to the column div, with a media query changing the flex-direction at the breakpoint of your choosing:

```
.column.col-6 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .column.col-6 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```